# Delay using flutter

Tags: flutter

I have splash screen with animation 
With the delay of some duration I check whether user has logged in previously or not.If yes,theh navigate it to HomeActivity otherwise LoginActivity.

But it doesn't goes ahead and is stuck on splash screen

Here is what I am doing

```
class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashRippleView(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashRippleView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashRippleViewState createState() => _SplashRippleViewState();
}

class _SplashRippleViewState extends State<SplashRippleView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  PageController pageController = new PageController();
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      lowerBound: 0.5,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    )..repeat();

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      checkloggedIn();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  checkloggedIn() async {
    bool loggedIn = await Preference().readBoolValue("login");
    if (loggedIn) {
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeActivity()));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Login()));
    }
  }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}
```

Comment: is there any error log? what is `Preference()`

Comment: no there is no error log .Preference() is my class for saving sharedpreference

Comment: make sure `Preference().readBoolValue` is returning a proper `bool`. I tried your code it is working fine. I'm assuming that your `build` method is returning a widget. try to print and check what `await Preference().readBoolValue("login");` is returning

Comment: I don't know why this happened but my code is working now

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. It is working for me.

```
void main() => runApp(Splash());

class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashRippleView(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashRippleView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashRippleViewState createState() => _SplashRippleViewState();
}

class _SplashRippleViewState extends State<SplashRippleView> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  PageController pageController = new PageController();
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      lowerBound: 0.5,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    )..repeat();

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      checkLoggedIn();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void checkLoggedIn() async {
    bool loggedIn = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => false);
    if (loggedIn) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeActivity()));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Splash"),),
      body: Center(child: Text("Splash screen")),
    );
  }
}

class HomeActivity extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home"),),
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login"),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this happened but my code is working now.